# problems faced in StringArray!

Tags: java

I declared a String -

```
  String operand[];
```

and i tried to initialize it as

```
operand[]0=string[2];(string[2]="buffer,x")
```

and it is returning a NPE,

The same happened while printing-

```
System.out.println(operand[1]);
```

is there any simple way to get this done?

thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You need to assign a real string array to `operand` first.

```
String[] operand = new String[3];  // or whatever number of elements you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but this will work:

```
String[] operand = new String[] { string[2] };
System.out.println(operand[0]);
```

Chris is also correct in what he is saying.

Answer (score 0):

In java **you cannot use an array object without initializing it**, which you are trying to do now. when you do this `String operand[];` it just declares that operand is an array of String but it wont allocates memory until you initialize it with new operator. So it throwing NPE.